# Executing a batch file to create a test file with xp_cmdshell - differentt results

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, dos

I'm trying to execute a batch file in SQL Server 2008 Express using xp_cmdshell. If I use it to execute a batch file that contains the following command:

echo > C:\development\test\itworks.txt

a file called "itworks.txt" is created and inside it text says "ECHO is on".
But if I run a batch file that contains the command:

CD. >test1.txt

it doesn't work (no error, just nothing created)
and neither does:

type NUL > test2.txt

although both those batch files do create the file if double clicked/run from command prompt. I thought it might be a permissions error (I hadn't tried the echo command at that point), so changed file permissions so that NTAuthority (which is what the SQLServer service runs as) had full control over the folder but it still didn't work. Nothing in event logs. I'm a novice at DOS commands so I don't really understand the different commands. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you test the commands directly at a command prompt, they work. The `cd` statement produces a text file containing the name of the current directory; the `type` statement produces a zero-byte file, but it does indeed produce a file.

Most likely, `xp_cmdshell` is executing in a folder where the account it's running under has no write privileges, and you're not specifying another location for the file to be written. (The `echo` statement that works specifies a folder location for the text file, while your other two don't.)

Change your batch file to:

```
cd > C:\development\test\test1.txt
```

or

```
type NUL > C:\development\test\test1.txt
```

If the `echo` statement works there when run via `xp_cmdshell`, you know it's writable by the NTAuthority account.

Comment: Doh! I should have spotted that the command that worked had the full path in, it's late and I'm tired. Thanks.